# CSS width 100% - margin-right

Tags: css, margin

Currently have 2 divs...left is full of content and right is a sidebar 300px wide. I'd like them to be side by side, left and right but can't seem to get it right. I need the left div to take up the whole screen less the 300px for the right div.

Is it possible to have the right div in the left divs right margin?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 100%
}
#left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 350px;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

**edit:**

Can i also have the right side position: fixed?
Solutions below work, but when i make the right div position: fixed; the div is no longer to the right of the left div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the right and left div order like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
</div>
```

Remove the `float:left` from `#left` in your CSS and change `#right` to `float:right`

```
#container {
    width: 100%
}
#left {
    margin-right: 350px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

EDIT:

My solution should work with `position: fixed;`, just remember to add `right:0` to the fixed div.

```
#container {
    width: 100%
}
#left {
    margin-right: 350px;
}
#right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your markup to:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS to:

```
#left {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

The left div will automatically take up the whole space next to the floated 'sidebar'.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-ordering the content, you could just add a `width:100%` and negative margin to the #left div.

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/FGMGB/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Left Col</div>
    <div id="right">Right Col</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 100%
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 100%; /* full width of #container */
    margin-right: -325px; /* #right's width + left & right padding & margin */
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

## **Edit**

From your comment elsewhere here, you need `#right` to be `position:fixed`. This will take the element completely out of the stack of elements, so `float` is unnecessary (and wont work anyways). Instead, just set the fixed positioning and you're good to go.

Relevant CSS, using same HTML as above

```
#container2 {
    width: 100%
}
#left2 {
    width: 100%; /* full width of #container */
    margin-right: -325px; /* #right's width + left & right padding & margin */
    background:#ddd;
}
#right2 {
    position:fixed;
    right:8px;
    top:28px; /* set the right and top to whatever positioning you need. */
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background:#444;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/FGMGB/1/)

Comment: Your solution for the `fixed width` does not work. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/FGMGB/)

Comment: @JodyT I just tested both methods in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE and they all seem to function as I'd expect. What seems to be not working - what does it not do that it should?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

Creating Liquid Layouts with Negative Margins (http://alistapart.com/article/negativemargins)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with some of the answers is that you may not want to re-order the content because you may want the ability to move the right div under the left div in a responsive design, which would get increasingly more difficult if we reorder the content.  Unfortunately @DACrosby's answer can lead to some wicked overlap of the right div on top of left div's content.

My solution was to set a positive `padding-right` that matches the negative `margin-right` on the left div, and set `box-sizing: border-box`.

```
.container {
    clear:both;
}
.left {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -325px;
    padding-right: 325px;
    background:#ddd;
}
.right {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:#666;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

This works with or without the `position:fixed;` right div.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fux4dvek/)